# Настройка зоны видимости сайта для мобильного. Viewport и медиазапрос

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, viewport

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу разобраться,как настроить зону видимости сайта для мобильных телефонов. На данный момент при загрузке сайта на мобильном,отображается верхний угол страницы, а дальше разве что масштабировать вручную. В коде прописана такая команда:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

Необходимо же,чтобы показывало зону шириной в 750 рх. Пробовала медиазапрос такого вида:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
@-ms-viewport { width: 750px; }
@-o-viewport { width: 750px; }
@viewport { width: 750px; }
}
```

Но никакого эффекта это не дало. Что делается не так?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер. Используйте такой метатег, он запретит мобильным браузерам скейлить ваш сайт:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Медиазапросы под популярные устройства можно посмотреть здесь [вот тут](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Для того, чтобы показывалась зона шириной 750px при ширине экрана меньшей, чем 750px, используйте такой медиазапрос:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 750px){
  body{
   width: 750px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Никак не реагирует на медиазапрос. Написала отдельным файлом CSS, подключила к шаблону сайта. Может дело в какой-то особенной работе шаблона сайта на битриксе?